# Elasticsearch failed to find analyzer on dev, but found locally

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch for my Spring Boot 3 application. I implemented a new custom analyzer (xyz_analyzer) to allow special characters as search parameters. Locally everything works fine. The custom analyzer is found and applied:

```
http://localhost:9200/efg.efgdata-000001/_analyze



{
    "analyzer": "xyz_analyzer",
    "text": "GmbH %26"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "gmbh",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "%26",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

But, after deploying it to our dev environment and forwarding the elastic search pod locally to the dev server, the analyzer can not be found anymore (same POST request):

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "failed to find analyzer [xyz_analyzer]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "failed to find analyzer [xyz_analyzer]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

NOTE THAT THE abc_analyzer can be found in all environments.

Here are my config files:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilterFactory;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerFactory;
import org.hibernate.search.backend.elasticsearch.analysis.ElasticsearchAnalysisConfigurationContext;
import org.hibernate.search.backend.elasticsearch.analysis.ElasticsearchAnalysisConfigurer;
import org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.analysis.LuceneAnalysisConfigurationContext;
import org.hibernate.search.backend.lucene.analysis.LuceneAnalysisConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CustomAnalysisConfigurer implements ElasticsearchAnalysisConfigurer, LuceneAnalysisConfigurer {

    public static final String ABC_ANALYZER = "abc_analyzer";

    public static final String XYZ_ANALYZER = "xyz_analyzer";

    @Override
    public void configure( ElasticsearchAnalysisConfigurationContext context ) {
        // filter section
        context.tokenFilter( "remove_whitespace" )
                .type( "pattern_replace" )
                .param( "pattern", "\\s+" )
                .param( "replacement", "" );

        context.tokenFilter( "remove_dash" )
                .type( "pattern_replace" )
                .param( "pattern", "-" )
                .param( "replacement", "" );

        // analyzer section
        context.analyzer( ABC_ANALYZER )
                .custom()
                .tokenizer( "keyword" )
                .tokenFilters( "lowercase", "remove_whitespace", "remove_dash" );

        context.tokenizer( "special_char_tokenizer" )
                .type( "whitespace" )
                .param( "token_chars", "letter", "digit", "symbol", "punctuation" );

        context.analyzer( XYZ_ANALYZER )
                .custom()
                .tokenizer( "special_char_tokenizer" )
                .tokenFilters( "lowercase" );

    }

    @Override
    public void configure( LuceneAnalysisConfigurationContext context ) {
        context.analyzer( ABC_ANALYZER )
                .custom()
                .tokenizer( StandardTokenizerFactory.class )
                .tokenFilter( LowerCaseFilterFactory.class );

        context.analyzer( XYZ_ANALYZER )
                .custom()
                .tokenizer( "special_char_tokenizer" )
                .tokenFilter( LowerCaseFilterFactory.class );
    }
}
```

and:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "remove_dash": {
      "pattern": "-",
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "replacement": ""
    },
    "remove_whitespace": {
      "pattern": "\\s+",
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "replacement": ""
    }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
    "special_char_tokenizer": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "filter": [
        "token_chars", "letter", "digit", "symbol", "punctuation"
      ]
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "abc_analyzer": {
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "remove_whitespace",
        "remove_dash"
      ],
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "keyword"
    },
    "xyz_analyzer": {
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ],
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "special_char_tokenizer"
    }
  }
}
```

and:

```
{
  "dynamic": "strict",
  "properties": {
    "_entity_type": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": false
    },
    "beginDate": {
      "type": "date",
      "doc_values": false,
      "format": "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSZZZZZ"
    },
    "A": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "B": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "C": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "D": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "doc_values": false
    },
    "E": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "city": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "F": {
          "type": "long",
          "doc_values": false
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "xyz_analyzer"
        },
        "G": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "H": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "I": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "J": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    },
    "K": {
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": false
    },
    "L": {
      "type": "date",
      "doc_values": false,
      "format": "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSZZZZZ"
    },
    "M": {
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": false
    },
    "ABCNumber": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "abc_analyzer"
    },
    "N": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "O": {
      "type": "date",
      "doc_values": false,
      "format": "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSZZZZZ"
    },
    "P": {
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": false
    },
    "Q": {
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": false
    },
    "R": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "S": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "T": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "U": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

and for my entity:

```
@FullTextField( searchable = Searchable.YES, projectable = Projectable.YES, analyzer = ABC_ANALYZER )
    @Size( max = 20 )
    @Column( name = "ABC_NUMBER" )
    private String ABCNumber;

@FullTextField( searchable = Searchable.YES, projectable = Projectable.YES, analyzer = XYZ_ANALYZER )
    @Column( name = "NAME" )
    private String name;
```

SETTINGS:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/efg.efgdata-000001/_settings

local:

{
    "efg.efgdata-000001": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "routing": {
                    "allocation": {
                        "include": {
                            "_tier_preference": "data_content"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "efg.efgdata-000001",
                "creation_date": "1696403353164",
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "remove_dash": {
                            "pattern": "-",
                            "type": "pattern_replace",
                            "replacement": ""
                        },
                        "remove_whitespace": {
                            "pattern": "\\s+",
                            "type": "pattern_replace",
                            "replacement": ""
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "abc_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "remove_whitespace",
                                "remove_dash"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "keyword"
                        },
                        "xyz_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "special_char_tokenizer"
                        }
                    },
                    "tokenizer": {
                        "special_char_tokenizer": {
                            "token_chars": [
                                "letter",
                                "digit",
                                "symbol",
                                "punctuation"
                            ],
                            "type": "whitespace"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "G1XVBph-TeGd5RpfETKsFg",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7120099"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Dev:

{
    "efg.efgdata-000001": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "routing": {
                    "allocation": {
                        "include": {
                            "_tier_preference": "data_content"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "efg.efgdata-000001",
                "creation_date": "1689166583198",
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "remove_dash": {
                            "pattern": "-",
                            "type": "pattern_replace",
                            "replacement": ""
                        },
                        "remove_whitespace": {
                            "pattern": "\\s+",
                            "type": "pattern_replace",
                            "replacement": ""
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "abc_analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "remove_whitespace",
                                "remove_dash"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "9gIpm08iRba32EDhgaaskA",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7171199"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you get when running `GET efg.efgdata-000001/_settings` in both of your environments?

Comment: I added the responses to the question. As you can see the new analyzer is missing.

Comment: You can see the `xyz_analyzer` as well as `special_char_tokenizer` are not present in your `efg.efgdata-000001` dev index. Also in your `configure` method you have `XYZ_ANALYZER` twice, I thin the first one should be `ABC_ANALYZER`

Comment: Sorry i just made a mistake when renaming the data. The first one is ABC and the second XYZ, I updated it. Yes I see that special_char_tokenizer and xyz_analyzer is not present in the dev index. Thats what I don't understand

Comment: If you delete everything and start clean in both environments, I guess you get the same errors in both

Comment: can you explain that a bit more precisely please ^^